# Find out which GCP project is hosting which AppEngine or which GCS Bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-storage, cname

We have many projects inside our Organization GCP account.
We have many legacy GCS Buckets and many legacy AppEngines hosted inside our various projects.
All these Buckets and AppEngines are served via custom CNAME.
We use a separate DNS service outside GCP to manage our DNS records.

---

The problem we are facing today is, for legacy these Buckets and legacy AppEngines, every DNS record says the CNAME value is `ghs.googlehosted.com`. We are now struggling to locate:

- which CNAME entry is for a Bucket
- which CNAME entry is for an AppEngine
- which of our MANY GCP projects is hosting the Bucket/AppEngine of that CNAME record

How do we find this out when there 200+ projects in the GCP account?

Answer (score 1):

The [Asset Inventory API](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types) would be able to help with both App Engine and Cloud Storage.